# Open a hyperlink from Reporting Services in a new window and pass through a value

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created a hyperlink from my report and pass through a value successfully.

```
="http://Applicationlive:8080/ApplicationName/secure/EventReportPage.zul?EventReportId=" & Fields!event_report_id.Value
```

Now I want to open it in a new window.

I've tried variations of

```
=”javascript:void(window.open(‘http://Applicationlive:8080/ApplicationName/secure/EventReportPage.zul?EventReportId=" & Fields!event_report_id.Value,’_blank’))”
```

With no joy, either the hyperlink doesn't do anything or the report doesn't preview.

Is it possible to pass though a report value into a web application url in a new window? and if so can you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Created the Link Url in the Query-

```
           '<a href = "javascript:void(window.open(''http://Applicationlive:8080/ApplicationName/secure/  EventReportPage.zul?EventReportId='
            + CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), event_report_id)
            + ''',''_blank''));">' + linkDescription + '</a>' [Link]
```

Then in the report i went to place holder properties and interpreted HTML tags as styles.

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Thank you for this, this is the first time I have attempted this. Currently I'm getting the error ( 'Return' statement in a Function, Get, or Operator must return a value) Do I just create a placeholder, copy and paste the Link URL into the Value and select Interpreted  HTML tags as styles or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Build the Link in the Query, place the Link in the proper cell, then highlight the [Link] right click and click Placeholder Properties..  then under markup type hit the radio for Html.